# Get al scheduled tasks from CRON4J Scheduler

Tags: scheduler, cron4j

I am using cron4j to manage timing of some tasks. I have a need to be able to get a list of all tasks added to a given scheduler. Please note that I care about MORE than simply the tasks that are currently executing.

I was trying to use this :

```
TaskExecutor[] executingTasks = context.getScheduler().getExecutingTasks();
```

But that of course only seems to give me the one task that is currently executing not the 7 others that are laying dormant until their scheduled run time.

Does anyone have any Idea how to get a simple list of tasks that are attached to a given scheduler?